# writing an xml file to response in generic handler

Tags: asp.net, xml

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(file.InputStream));

var wr = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(wr);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(wr.GetStringBuilder().ToString()));
```

This is resulting in a corrupt xml file. The string looks like this:

```
"\u003c?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?\u003e\r\n\u003cAuditSheet\u003e\r\n  \u003cPLANT_SITE_CUSTOMER_NAME\u003eZINIFEX HOBART SMELTER\u003c/PLANT_SITE_CUSTOMER_NAME\u003e\r\n
```

Did i miss something obvious here? Do i need to remove the `\r\n` manually? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be serializing the string.

Instead, you should write directly to the HTTP response by calling `doc.Save(response.Output)`.

Comment: Yea, just noticed. To much copy paste from serializing JSON :-) Thanks for answering